# Testing with argumentCaptor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Im using ArgumentCaptor to capture the internal call of PreparedStatementCreator.

```
public void update(Item item) {
   String sql = "SET NAME = ? where ID = ?";
   jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
     @Override
     public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) {
       final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1, item.getName());
       ps.setInt(1, item.getId());
     }
   });
 }
```

Below is the test with ArgumentCaptor.

```
      @Test
      public void testUpdate() {
        Item item= new Item("1","testName");
        ArgumentCaptor<PreparedStatementCreator> pscArgCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PreparedStatementCreator.class);
        insert(item);
        verify(mockJdbc, times(1)).update(pscArgCaptor .capture());
        assertNotNull(pscArgCaptor.getValue(); 
        assertEquals(pscArgCaptor , ?);
      }
```

I can successful capture the PreparedStatementCreator call when I call update. I used assertNotNull to test and see if the pscArgcaptor was something. I dont know how to get inside this object to verify my parameters in the prepared statement such as `ps.setString(1, item.getId()` and `ps.setString(1, item.getName()` to ensure that the prepared statement is the correct one. Is it possible to do without any getters from PreparedStatementCreator?

Comment: Frankly, this is the kind of things you should not mock. Call your actual code, and check that the exepected data is inserted/updated in the database.

Comment: I would add  to the JB Nizet comment : by using an in memory database.

Comment: @davidxxx unless you actually care that your code works on your actual production database.

Comment: @JB Nizet  Unit tests and integration tests are complementary. Production database should be used for integration tests and not for local tests but if you want to have slow builds or potential side effects between unit tests.

Comment: @JBNizet *"Frankly, this is the kind of things you should not mock. Call your actual code, and check that the exepected data is inserted/updated in the database."* This would turn it into an *Acceptance test*. Unittests should *never* communicate with dependencies outside the RAM.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you're arguing about the best name to give to that kind of test. I don't really care about that. I care about writing tests that make sense, and give me confidence that my code does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @JBNizet I care about that UnitTests follow the FIRST and RTFM principles so that they are of any use. If they don't they will not be executed as often as needed and then they are not useful.

Comment: Good for you. I'll have a tiny bit slower tests that prove my code is OK. You'll have a tiny bit faster tests that... will run a tiny bit faster and won't prove anything. Note that you're the only one arguing about how these tests should be named. I never said anywhere that the tests I suggest implementing are unit tests.

Comment: @JBNizet *"I'll have a tiny bit slower tests that prove my code is OK."* You have a strange definition of *tiny*... I want my unittests (for the actual changed production code) to run each time I press <ctrl><s>. It is not acceptable executing all tests (for the actual changed production code) taking longer than 500ms. How many Database accessing tests can you run in this time? I run up to 100 unittests.

Comment: You're missing the point. I prefer 1 test running in 5 seconds (although they're of course much faster than that) and making sure my code is correct than 100 tests running in 500ms and not making sure of anything. Note that the test in your answer passes, and forces the code to be more complex than necessary, although the code is obviously incorrect: the SQL is wrong, and it's setting the parameter at index 1 twice. You just proved my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your *code under test* instantiates   its dependencies (here the instance of `PreparedStatementCreator`) itself.

Instead you should *inject* an instance of it. In that case you could inject a mock of `PreparedStatementCreator` and capture the parameters passed to that mock.

---

> I'm fairly new to Junit and Mocking.

This is not so much about *mocking* but about *Single Responsibility/Separation of Concerns*. It improves reusability of your code. Testability is a sign of reusable code.

> What do you mean by inject a mock. Could you provide me an example?

the problem here is that the interface `PreparedStatementCreator` does not provide a suitable interface to be used with the `Item` class as a parameter. Therefore it is usefull to introduce a *factory class*:

```
public class ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory{
   public PreparedStatementCreator createFor(Item item){
     return new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
         public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) {
           final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( "SET NAME = ? where ID = ?");
           ps.setString(1, item.getName());
           ps.setInt(1, item.getId());
           return ps;
         }
       })
    }
}
```

You would pass an instance of that class as constructor parameter to your code under test:

Your code under test could look like this:

```
public class YourDaoClass { 
  private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  private final ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory preparedStatementCreatorFactory;
  public YourDaoClass(ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory preparedStatementCreatorFactory, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    this.preparedStatementCreatorFactory = preparedStatementCreatorFactory;
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }
```

Then the method under test would change to:

```
public void update(Item item) {
  jdbcTemplate.update(preparedStatementCreatorFactory.createFor(item));
}
```

And you would have separate tests for your code under test.

```
public class YourDaoClassTest{
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Mock
    private ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory preparedStatementCreatorFactory;
    @Mock
    private PreparedStatementCreator preparedStatementCreator;

    YourDaoClass yourDaoClass;


    @Before
    public void setup(){
      // I prefer direct object creation over @InjectMocks since the latter does not raise compile errors on missing constructor arguments...
      yourDaoClass = new YourDaoClass(preparedStatementCreatorFactory,jdbcTemplate); 
    }  


    @Test
    public void passesItemToStatementFactory(){
       Item item = new Item();
       doReturn(preparedStatementCreator)
            .when(preparedStatementCreatorFactory)
            .createFor(item);

       yourDaoClass-update(item);

       InOrder inOrder= inOrder(preparedStatementCreatorFactory,jdbcTemplate);
       inOrder.verify(preparedStatementCreatorFactory).createFor(item);
       inOrder.verify(jdbcTemplate).update(preparedStatementCreator);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactoryTest{
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    @Mock
    private Connection connection;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
      // maybe exchange anyString() with an ArgumentCaptor
       doReturn(preparedStatement).when(connection).prepareStatement(anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void passesNameAndIdToPreparedStatement(){
       Item item = new Item();
       item.setName("an valid name");
       item.setID(ANY_VALID_ID);

       ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory itemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory =
           new ItemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory();
       PreparedStatement createdPreparedStatement = itemPreparedStatementCreatorFactory.createFor(item);

       verify(createdPreparedStatement).setString(1, item.getName());
       verify(createdPreparedStatement).setInt(1, item.getId());
   }
}
```

#### conclusion

When ever you have difficulties to test your production code it most likely is not written in an reusable way violating the SRP/SoC principles.

On the other hand the tests shown are dumb because there is no real logic to verify because the production code is "too simple to fail" and the tests basically repeat what the code does. Usually such tests are not really useful since they are to tightly coupled with the implementation and break when the implementation changes.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Junit and Mocking. What do you mean by inject a mock. Could you provide me an example?